# Alignment of Tables in the Labels Class doesnt work

Tags: tables

i use Sharelatex.com and i wanted to use the labels class to make labels (http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/labels/labels.pdf)

the content of cells in the tabulars dont align anymore when used inside the labels

if i place it outside the labels it works fine. i dont understand enough of latex to find the problem. i hope someone can help.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{labels}
\LabelCols=3% Number of columns of labels per page
\LabelRows=7% Number of rows of labels per page
\LeftBorder=8mm% Space added to left border of each label
\RightBorder=8mm% Space added to right border of each label
\TopBorder=9mm% Space to leave at top of sheet
\BottomBorder=2mm% Space to leave at bottom of sheet
\LabelGridtrue
\begin{document}% End of preamble
{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
{

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
  aaa & rr \\
  aaaaaa & rrrrr
\end{tabular}

\begin{labels}
\textbf{Anlage 12}
\textbf{HV Trendgrafik}\break
Betrieb
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
 aaa & rr \\
 aaaaaa & rrrrr
\end{tabular}
Datum: 
\end{labels}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to our site. You will have to do `\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}%` with that percent sign in the end. I would consider that a bug IMO. If you have an emailadress of the author of that package (it's not a class), you could link her/him to this.

Comment: thx, it works now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need a `%` sign after the final `\\` in addition for the alignment to work correctly, as you will see if you include a third line in your alignment which reads the same as the first line: that line has the "aaa" centred unless you finish the previous line with `\\%`.

What happens in the labels environment is that every end-of-line character is treated as an instruction to start a new paragraph.  (If this behaviour were not there, you would have "Anlage 12 HV ..." all on one line, and no line gap between "Trendgrafik" and "Betrieb".  You can turn this behaviour off using `\genericlabel`, as documented in the package documentation.)

In (La)TeX, this is achieved by making the new line character an "active" character.  In the labels package, it performs this task by (first inserting an empty box in horizontal mode, then) starting a new paragraph by doing an implicit `\\`.  This runs the `\newline` macro, which finishes the previous line by doing an `\hfil`, then starts a new line by `\break`.  But within a `tabular` environment, `\break` has no effect (as you're not building paragraphs), so you're left with an `\hfil` which causes the line to be centred.

The left alignment works fine within tabulars within labels in columns 2 and onwards; it is just this implicit new line behaviour (which is usually desirable) which has the effect of messing up the first column of tabulars.

This cannot be sensibly handled at a package level, as it is not obvious when to switch off this behaviour within the context of a label.

So there are two options:

1. Use `\genericlabel` and handle your line breaks manually, thus:

   ```
   \genericlabel{%
   \begin{tabular}{l}
   \textbf{Anlage 12}\\
   \textbf{HV Trendgrafik}\\[\medskipamount]
   Betrieb\\
   \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
    aaaaaa & rr\\
    aaa & rrrrr
   \end{tabular}\\
   Datum:
   \end{tabular}}
   ```
2. Use a `%` at the end of each line within a `tabular` (but not after the final `\end{tabular}`):

   ```
   \begin{labels}
   \textbf{Anlage 12}
   \textbf{HV Trendgrafik}\break
   Betrieb
   \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}%
    aaaaaa & rr\\%
    aaa & rrrrr%
   \end{tabular}
   Datum:
   \end{labels}
   ```

I hope this explanation is of help!

Julian (who was the last person to edit the `labels.sty` package)

Comment: thx julian for the in-depth answer

Answer (score 0):

As described in comment, there was a % sign missing. This is not an expected behaviour for sure. The author of `labels` is writing about some wrong space fix for the address labels which use `tabular` as well. Maybe this was the very same issue. Should get fixed so please consider reporting this.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{labels}
\LabelGridtrue

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\begin{labels}
    \textbf{Anlage 12}
    \textbf{HV Trendgrafik}\break
    Betrieb
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}%
        aaa & rr \\
        aaaaaa & rrrrr
    \end{tabular}
    Datum: 
\end{labels}
\end{document}
```

[image]